# If loop while trying to hide every div except for one

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am in the process of creating a facebook style event invitation script. I have gotten the friends to display in my modal etc, the problem I'm having is that when you select a category the script that the category button calls on should hide all the divs in the group_friends container except for the div with the current id being queried. This is the function I am working on:

```
function get_group_friends(element){
var group_id=($(element).attr("id")); 

console.log((($("div[id^="+group_id+"]")).children()).length);

if(((($(".div[id^="+group_id+"]").children()).length)) == 0)
     {

      $("#container_group_friends").children().not($("div[id^="+group_id+"]")).hide();
       $("#container_all_friends").hide();

  var query = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = "+($(element).attr("id"))+" AND uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))"; 
FB.api({access_token: accessToken, method:'fql.query', query: query}, function(response_group_friend)
{
   var i=0;
   var result_group_friend="";
   for(i=0; i<response_group_friend.length; i++)
   {
      result_group_friend+="<div class='fbfriends' id='"+response_group_friend[i].uid+"' ><div class='user float_left'><img src='"+response_group_friend[i].pic_square+"'/><div class='tick'></div></div><div class='friend_name float_left'>"+response_group_friend[i].name+"</div></div>";

   }   $("div[id^="+group_id+"]").append(result_group_friend);

  //    $("#container_group_friends").append($("div[id^="+group_id+"]"));
 });

}
 else
{
        ($("#container_group_friends").children().not($("div[id^="+group_id+"]"))).hide();
      $("#container_all_friends").hide();
 }

}
```

The problem is that when I click on another category, everything in the container is invisible even the div with the specific id being queried. I am probably not looking at this as logically as I should. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: We need to see your HTML to know what jQuery best manipulates it.

Comment: `if(((($(".div[id^="+group_id+"]").children()).length)) == 0)` --> 
`if(!$(".div[id^="+group_id+"]").children().length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a couple of assumptions, the code should simplify as follows:

```
function get_group_friends(element) {
    var group_id = $(element).attr("id");
    var $groupContainer = $("div[id^=" + group_id + "]");
    $("#container_group_friends").children().not($groupContainer).hide();
    $("#container_all_friends").hide();
    //console.log($groupContainer.children().length);
    if( $groupContainer.children().length == 0 ) {
        var query = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = " + group_id + " AND uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))";
        FB.api({access_token: accessToken, method:'fql.query', query: query}, function(response_group_friend) {
            $.each(response_group_friend, function(i, f) {
                $groupContainer.append("<div class='fbfriends' id='" + f.uid + "' ><div class='user float_left'><img src='" + f.pic_square + "'/><div class='tick'></div></div><div class='friend_name float_left'>" + f.name + "</div></div>");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Barring mistakes on my part, nothing should have changed.

The problem appears to be that there's no statement which shows the current group container, so it remains hidden if another group (ie. category) was previously selected.

Try changing line 3 of my code above to:

```
var $groupContainer = $("div[id^=" + group_id + "]").show();
```

Comment: Yup this did it for me. Had to change line 3 to what you suggested so that clicking on another category will process accordingly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is unwanted dot in 4th line of code. One before 'div' inside the selector. Are you sure, that `div` literal you are using there is the class name?

`if(((($(".div[id^="+group_id+"]").children()).length)) == 0)
if($("div[id^="+group_id+"]").children().length == 0)`

Secondly, but I'm not 100% sure. You probably missed double `not` statement here:

> $("#container_group_friends").children().***not***($("div[***id^=**"+group_id+"]")).hide();

I'd convert this expression into single selector:

> $("#container_group_friends > div:not(#" + group_id + ")").hide()